# Notation of plus with a dot above it \dotplus

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Question regarding notation of internal/ external direct sum.

I am referring to Richard Pierce's book Associative Algebras, where he uses two notations for direct sum $\oplus$ and $\dotplus$.

I am assuming one of them refers to external direct sum, one refers to internal direct sum, but not sure which is which?

Thanks for help.

Update: In the beginning of the book the author said "We will denote the product of a finite set $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ of algebras by $A_1\dotplus A_2\dotplus \dots \dotplus A_n$."

Comment: Does he not state his convention somewhere near the beginning of the book?  This is not a standard convention I've ever seen...

Comment: He said "We will denote the product of a finite set $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ of algebras by $A_1\dotplus A_2\dotplus \dots \dotplus A_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [index of symbols](https://books.google.com/books?id=j8PSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&pg=PA426#v=onepage&q&f=false) at the end of the book, $\dotplus$ denotes the product of algebras, while $\oplus$ denotes the direct sum of modules.

Comment: By product, does he mean Cartesian Product?

Comment: Yes (well, he defines it as the categorical product, but that is the same thing, up to canonical isomorphism).