# Explanation of notation of dot above plus $\dotplus$ for matrices

Tags: notation, several-complex-variables

I am studying Y Kubota's article  "A note on holomorphic imbeddings of the classical Cartan domanis into the unit ball". There is a phrase in the article

> Considering a skew-symmetric matrix $Z$ of order $q$ such that $$Z=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & a_1\\
> -a_1&0 \end{array}\right)\dotplus\ldots\dotplus \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & a_m\\
> -a_m&0 \end{array}\right),$$ where q=2m and $a_1,\ldots, a_m\in{\mathbb{C}}$.

Clearly, the expressions on the right are $2\times 2$ matrices and the expression on left is a matrix of order $2m$, but what does the symbol $\dotplus$ mean.

I found similar notation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669849/notation-of-plus-with-a-dot-above-it-dotplus) but it is for product of algebras. Can someone help me understand what it means, if it is a standard notation or what it means.

Comment: I would guess it means $$
I_1  \dotplus  \cdots  \dotplus I_n  = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {I_1 } &  \cdots  & 0  \\
    \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \\
   0 &  \cdots  & {I_n }  \\
\end{array}} \right).
$$

Comment: Does he not define the symbol somewhere? I wouldn't say that this is standard notation.

Comment: It is not mentioned what it means, it is used without stating what it means, that made me thought it is standard notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1980 article "[A Note on Holomorphic Imbeddings of the Classical Cartan Domains into the Unit Ball](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2043283)" by Yoshihisa Kubota uses $\dotplus$ and cites the 1944 article "[On the Theory of Automorphic Functions of a Matrix Variable I-Geometrical Basis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371910)" by Loo-Keng Hua, who writes in Theorem 7:

> Let $Z$ be a non-singular skew-symmetric matrix; then we have a unitary matrix $U$ such that $$UZU'=\begin{pmatrix}0&d_1\\-d_1&0\end{pmatrix}\dotplus\cdots\dotplus\begin{pmatrix}0&d_{n/2}\\-d_{n/2}&0\end{pmatrix}\text{,}$$ where $d_1^2,d_1^2,\cdots,d_{n/2}^2,d_{n/2}^2$ are the characteristic roots of $-Z\overline{Z}$.

For comparison, the [spectral theory section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory) of [the English Wikipedia page for skew-symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) says

> $$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
>   \begin{matrix}0 & \lambda_1 \\ -\lambda_1 & 0\end{matrix} &  0 & \cdots & 0 \\
>   0 & \begin{matrix}0 & \lambda_2 \\ -\lambda_2 & 0\end{matrix} & & 0 \\
>   \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
>   0 & 0 & \cdots & \begin{matrix}0 & \lambda_r\\ -\lambda_r & 0\end{matrix} \\
>     & & & & \begin{matrix}0 \\ & \ddots \\ & & 0 \end{matrix}
> \end{bmatrix}$$...every complex skew-symmetric matrix can be written in the form $A=U\Sigma U^{\mathrm{T}}$ where $U$ is unitary and $\Sigma$ has the block-diagonal form given above with $\lambda_k$ still real positive-definite.

With this context, I am fairly confident that $\dotplus$ as used by Kubota denotes the [**direct sum**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum) of matrices, which produces a block form as exemplified above and guessed by [gary](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83800/gary) in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3847248/explanation-of-notation-of-dot-above-plus-dotplus-for-matrices#comment7936258_3847248).